# Is there a difference between creating a class and declaring a class inside of another?

Tags: java

I'm wondering if there is any difference between creating a class in a new file and declaring one inside of another class, would it still be able to be referenced from outside of the class? I'm wondering because it would help my workplace be more organized.

Comment: Yes. Check [Nested Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: The tag changed dramatically since the Q was first posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) is the full documentation for nested classes.

If you want to know when to use inner classes (from [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)):

> **Compelling reasons for using nested classes include the following:**
>
> It is a way of logically grouping classes that are only used in one
>   place: If a class is useful to only one other class, then it is
>   logical to embed it in that class and keep the two together. Nesting
>   such "helper classes" makes their package more streamlined.
>
> It increases encapsulation: Consider two top-level classes, A and B,
>   where B needs access to members of A that would otherwise be declared
>   private. By hiding class B within class A, A's members can be declared
>   private and B can access them. In addition, B itself can be hidden
>   from the outside world.
>
> It can lead to more readable and maintainable code: Nesting small
>   classes within top-level classes places the code closer to where it is
>   used.

Yes, you can access your inner classes from other classes. (read about [controlling access to members of a class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)).

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/examples/ShadowTest.java) you can find an example on how to access inner class from "outside" of the class.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and documentation! This isn't tagged incorrectly, is it? Due to it not being specifically about code.

Comment: I think the tag is correct, it is a java question. @zachwirta